# use fn keys to raise volume to 150% in xfce mint

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

In cinnamon I have the option to make my fn keys go over 100% using the amplification.

I can not find any such option in xfce version of linux mint. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system tray in Mint Xfce has a speaker icon, I believe by default (if not, right-click the tray, click on `panel`, click `Add new items`, and add `PulseAudio Plugin`).

If you click the speaker icon, you get a little volume control panel, which includes a slider for the speakers.  You can adjust that up to 150%.

If you right-click the speaker icon and then click on Properties, one of the options you can select is `Enable keyboard shortcuts for volume control`.

There is a Help button on that window, which takes you to the "online manual".  Unfortunately, that manual appears to be a useless single paragraph that mentions the option to use multimedia keys.  I'm guessing this refers to dedicated extra keys or dual-function keys with volume icons on them.  You would need to experiment with what keys, if any on your keyboard, control the volume when that option is selected.

If your keyboard doesn't have dedicated or labeled multimedia keys, try different function keys and navigation keys (and even the `+` and `-` keys in the number row at the top of the regular keyboard keys), alone and in combination with modifier keys (shift, ctrl, alt, fn).

If your keyboard can't produce the volume control keycodes, you may be able to program your own key combinations.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342554/how-to-enable-my-keyboards-volume-keys-in-xfce.